# How to include the boost project in my c++ code

Tags: c++, boost

I'm attempting to write a super trivial program using Boost's cpp-netlib to parse an HTTP URL in an example c++ file.

The code is as trivial as:

```
#include <boost/network/uri>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::network;

int main() {
    uri::uri instance("http://www.example.com");
    std::cout << "scheme: " << instance.scheme() << std::endl
        << "host: " << instance.host() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My test code is in the same directory as where the boost source is. To compile I simply do:

`g++ -Icpp-netlib-0.12.0-final -o test test.cpp`

It's not finding the include with `-I` passed though and I'm getting a fatal error.

```
fatal error: 'boost/network/uri' file not found
#include <boost/network/uri>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

What's the correct way to do this to begin writing example code using their library?

Comment: I don't know about boost much, but are you sure you should use `boost/network/uri` instead of `boost/network/uri.hpp`?

Comment: That gave me a new error. Fatal error: `#include <boost/config.hpp>` I see a `config.hpp` in `boost/network/uri/` but I don't see `boost/config.hpp` in the directory.

Comment: I think your boost install is broken then. Perhaps you do not have the development package installed?

Answer (score 2):

Guessing from this:

> My test code is in the same directory as where the boost source is.

If what you have is that you have unpacked the boost headers to your source code directory, then your include statement wont work. An #include with <> only searches for the include files in the standard include paths (/usr/include & so forth).

So you can try the include statement with "" instead, which will search from the current source directory too, or better yet, install an official boost development package to your computer using the package manager in your distro.

The compiler command line parameter "-Icpp-netlib-0.12.0-final" would help the compiler to find boost if you had the directory  "cpp-netlib-0.12.0-final/boost" in the source code directory where you launch g++.

Answer (score 1):

1. Regarding your Boost install, did you properly install and link `Boost.date_time`? Much of Boost is header-only; here, `Boost.system` and `Boost.Regex`, and don't need a separate binary. However, but `Boost.Date_time` has a separate binary library, and there are additional installation steps needed to use it. [Ref 2]

   > Although Boost is mostly header only, applications built using
   >   cpp-netlib still requires linking with Boost.System, Boost.Date_time,
   >   and Boost.Regex. [Ref 1]
2. Is your Boost library above version 1.50.0?
3. Did you set your `BOOST_ROOT` environment variable?

> The path to the boost root directory (often /usr/local/boost_1_60_0)
>   is sometimes referred to as $BOOST_ROOT in documentation and mailing
>   lists [Ref 2]

4. Is Boost installed in `/usr/local`? You may need `root` access to do this.
5. Did you check the permissions on your installation? If you installed as root, you may need to `chmod` 755 permissions to your non-root account(s)

References:
1. http://cpp-netlib.org/0.12.0/getting_started.html#getting-started
2. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

Hope this helps.